# Drush "unable to fork" on CentOS 6

Tags: drush

On a Centos 6.5 box, I'm having difficulty with drush dl, the following errors are presented:

```
$ drush dl profile2
exec(): Unable to fork [wget --version 2>&1] exec.inc:150                                                                            [warning]
exec(): Unable to fork [curl --version 2>&1] exec.inc:150                                                                            [warning]
exec(): Unable to fork [which curl 2>&1] exec.inc:150                                                                                [warning]
wget nor curl executables found.
```

Both curl and wget are installed on this box, both residing in /usr/bin.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see if your have your curl extension in php and on your server?

Comment: yes I did.  i can see it's enabled as well with `drush ev 'print phpinfo();'`.  here's the full output of that: http://pastebin.com/nHaT1LBB

Comment: But is curl installed on the server, its not just a php extension

Comment: well then, yes it is also installed on the server. in /usr/bin along with wget

Comment: Maybe you have reached [process limit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20648949)? Note that "Unable to fork" toes **not** mean the command cannot be found, just for some reason it **cannot be started**. Can you `wget` on your own, from command line? Can you `wget` using `exec()` in simplistic php script? And so on... I'm not an admin to tell.

Comment: @Mołot I think you're on to something.  I can't even run `drush ev "echo system('ulimit -a');"`, it returns `system(): Unable to fork [ulimit -a] core.drush.inc(1100) : eval()'d code:1`.

However, `ulimit -a` shows max_user_processes as 1024, but `ps -L -u ravery | wc -l` shows only 5 processes running.

Comment: Time to seriously talk to your sysadmin...

Comment: I'm the sysadmin for this, it's a rackspace cloud box I'm using for hosting my own site. :(